CMake version does not mach
I was trying to get the LBPH classifier for Java for OpenCV and to do that I need to use cmake. For this case thy are saying that the minimum version for the cmake is: "3.29" and I had 3.22.
I upgraded as it is suggested here: how I upgreaded
I am trying to use this command with cmake:
"cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/alex/opencv_contrib" as it is presented in here: cmake
But I still have this error:
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
  call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
  both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_define_module".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

and I have used the "cmake --version" command and this is the result:
cmake version 3.29.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).


The error messages that you've posted seem to indicate it is a problem with the developer's CMakeLists.txt files -- it isn't complaining about your version of cmake at all.  A lot of them are actually warnings; the error is actually about the missing ocv_define_module command.  It looks like there is a problem with the CMakeLists.txt files and not with anything you did (so far).  You should ask the developers for help.

The error I see is Unknown CMake command "ocv_define_module" - it doesn't indicate anything about CMake version. I suspect you are running the cmake command from the wrong location - AFAIK it needs to be executed in the top level opencv directory (ocv_define_module is a macro defined in the cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake file).

I did it over there as well, I do not know what should I do more.

OK well if you want further help please [edit] your question to show the actual layout of your source tree - fyi the recommended procedure is to have the main opencv and opencv_contrib directories at the same level, then to create an out-of-tree build dir also at that level and build inside of that (so that the extra modules directory and source directory become relative paths ../opencv_contrib-4.x/modules and ../opencv-4.x). See for example Build with opencv_contrib

I did it after 1 hour with cmake-gui because it is an option to import more libraries there that I did not know about and I needed only the 4.9.0 version apparently for the project due to maven dependencies.
